# How generate a DOC and a PDF from html <div> in Django

Tags: django

Good day,

In Django project I have an html file with a div in which some fields(like p) change the content by radiobutton choice (using JavaScript).

Need to turn the div with the changed content (by radiobutton choice) into pdf and doc (with saving of all styles).
Any help is appreciated.

I tried "wkhtmltopdf" but it generates pdf only with model contents from db and without result of radiobutton work.

```
<!--Choice radiobuttons-->

function Display(obj) {
    fioid=obj.id;
    if(fioid=='exampleRadios1'){
        document.getElementById("fiz").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("ip").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("ur").style.display='none';

}   else if(fioid=='exampleRadios2'){
        document.getElementById("ip").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("fiz").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("ur").style.display='none';

}   else if(fioid=='exampleRadios3'){
        document.getElementById("ur").style.display='block';
        document.getElementById("fiz").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("ip").style.display='none';

}}


<div class="col-12">
   <div class="form-check">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" 
     id="exampleRadios1" value="FIZ" onclick="Display(this);" checked>
         <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                    FIZ
         </label>
   </div>

  <div class="form-check">
     <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" 
     id="exampleRadios2" value="IP" onclick="Display(this);">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                    IP
          </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-check">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" 
      id="exampleRadios3" value="UR" onclick="Display(this);">
           <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                      UR
           </label>
  </div>
</div>


<div>
    <p style="text-align: justify; font-family: Times New Roman;">
    <span style='display: block;' id="fiz">This is FIZ</span>
    <span style='display: none;' id="ip">This is IP</span>
    <span style='display: none;' id="ur">This is UR</span>
    </p>
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may be answer to the question.
https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-to-word-doc-docx-using-javascript/